# Unsupported resolution of Watch Dogs

Tags: technical-issues, watch-dogs

Actually a game's "Watch Dog's" default resolution isn't supported by my LCD.
How to change its default resolution without opening the game?
My LCD monitor's resolution is 1024x768 60Hz.

Answer (score 2):

Try edit the configuration file located at `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Watch_Dogs\<user-id>\GamerProfile.xml` (Remember to replace the `<user-id>` with your user id. Open it up with any text editor you like (Personally I recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), but notepad is ok.)

After the tag `<RenderProfile`, search for something like `ResolutionX="1024" ResolutionY="768"`. Change the value between the `""` to what you want.

To change the refresh rate, search for something like `RefreshRate="60"` and change the value to what you want.

Comment: Plug it into a t.v?

Comment: I couldn't find this file but folder is available

Comment: Can you provide me this file so that I can copy it to that folder.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here are the file: http://www.mediafire.com/view/d4mffc6cpj3sf0r/GamerProfile.xml
I hope I can help you.

Comment: Remember to place it at %USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Watch_Dogs\<user-id>\GamerProfile.xml and replace <user-id> with your user id.